# How assign role to user in discord by slash command?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How assign role to user in discord by slash command?
This is my discord code by node.js using discord.js module.
After finish this code, I want add role on ready event.
Please fixt:
This small code doesn't working.

```
else if (command === "red") {
            // Create a new text channel
            let role = guild.roles.find((r) => r.id === "948192740632588329");
            // Or add it to yourself
            message.member.roles.add(role);
        }
```

in below.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const {
    Client,
    Intents,
    MessageEmbed,
    MessageAttachment,
} = require("discord.js");
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});


client.on("messageCreate", function (message) {
    let guild = message.guild;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    const args = commandBody.split(" ");
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === "ping") {
        const timeTaken = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
        message.reply(`Pong! This message had a latency of ${timeTaken}ms.`);
    } else if (command === "sum") {
        const numArgs = args.map((x) => parseFloat(x));
        const sum = numArgs.reduce((counter, x) => (counter += x));
        message.reply(`The sum of all the arguments you provided is ${sum}!`);
    } else if (command === "channel") {
        // Create a new text channel
        guild.channels
            .create("nft-checking", { reason: "Needed a cool new channel" })
            .then(console.log)
            .catch(console.error);
    } else if (command === "red") {
        // Create a new text channel
        let role = guild.roles.find((r) => r.id === "948192740632588329");
        // Or add it to yourself
        message.member.roles.add(role);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if (command === "ping") {
const timeTaken = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
message.reply(`ping! This message had a latency of ${timeTaken}ms.`);

Replace these line with this
Or
Just correct the spelling of from pong to ping.